# Ограничение количества бронирований на пользователя с PHP и MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli

И так. Бронирование книг. Я решила сделать так, чтобы человек мог забронировать не более 5 книг за раз. И сделала такой запрос, который вытаскивать должен количество записей пользователя в числовом формате. Но у меня проблемы со сравнением.. Вернее. Я читала, что count() всегда возвращает больше, чем 0 на другом форуме. Но я так и не поняла, как, может, обнулить его? Вот часть моего кода.

```
    <?php
            else
            {
                $users_id = $_SESSION['user']['id'];
                $ress = $connect->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM reservation WHERE users_id = $users_id")->fetch_assoc();
                if ($ress >= 5)
                {
                echo "<h2>Вы можете забронировать не более 5 книг одновременно.</h2>";
                }else
                {
                $dir='';
                $date_today = date('d-m-Y');
                $time = strtotime("+1 month");
                $fecha = date("d-m-Y", $time);
                $query = "INSERT INTO `reservation`".
                "(`book_id`, `users_id`, `bookissuingdate`, `bookreturndate`) VALUES".
                "('".$_POST['res_id']."', '".$users_id."', '".$date_today."', '".$fecha."');";
                $sql = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
                if ($sql)
                {
?>
            <h2>Данные о резерве добавлены.</h2>
<?php
                }
                else
                {
?>
            <h2>Произошла ошибка: <?php echo mysqli_error($connect); ?></h2>
<?php
                }
            }
```

Проблема в том, что он - if ($ress >= 5) - всегда говорит, что записей больше, чем 5, даже если их там нет вовсе. Помогите разобраться с этим, пожалуйста.

P.S. Я только что видела точно такой же вопрос на stackoverflow на английском, но там было лишь описание кода в общих чертах. И не говорилось про то, как избежать показывания >5 всегда.

Comment: Есть мнение, что `->fetch_assoc()` вернёт ассоциативный массив. В `$ress` должно быть что-то типа `array('count' -> 3)` или как-то так. Прежде, чем проводить проверку if - else, попробуйте вывести содержимое `$ress`. Если я прав, то необходимо условие переписать как-то так: `if ($ress['count'] >= 5) {...}`

Comment: Quazimorda, Да! Вы правы. Я пыталась вывести его, но он выдавал ошибку и я видимо плохо прочитала ее. Спасибо большое, теперь все работает!

Comment: чтобы вывести массив, используйте не echo, а `printr($ress)` или `var_dump($ress)`